# How can I check if a person has been selected from the Address Book before in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am building an app that relies on choosing people from the address book, and adding their information to an NSMutableArray. I only want each person chosen once, so I want the ability to grey out the people who have already been chosen. I am not sure where to look. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a list of already chosen users. For example, you can save them into CoreData store, SQLite table, plist file, etc. To compare currently selected user with those who are already on the list you'll need some unique identifier for every user. In most cases it's enough to store user's ID on the list, not the whole entity.

Comment: Alright, so is there a method I can call when loading the contacts that compares them and grays them out? Or do I have to create my own?

Comment: Of course iOS SDK doesn't contain ready-made solutions for all occasions. You should create your own data-store and write the code to get it worked with your needs.

Comment: I have never worked with data stores before. Is there a reason, in this case, to use it over NSDictionary? I mean, I'm only storing on value for lookup right?

Comment: `NSDictionary` will allow to check if selected user has already been added to the list. But if you want to keep this list between app's launches you'll need to write `NSDictionary` into some file and then read it from the file on every launch of the app.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Well, guess I have to learn how to write and read from plists then! Once I get that down, I have to figure out how to compare those values to the address book and gray out the choices.